# Ajax live search is not working after searching one value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

my page requires refreshing the page after every search. please any help. I am bignner for Ajax and here is my index page code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#live_search").keyup(function(){
      var input = $(this).val();
      //alert(input);

      if(input != ""){
        $.ajax({

          url:"livesearch.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{input:input},

          success:function(data){
           $("#searchresult").html(data);
          }
        });
      }else{
        $("#searchresult").css("display", "none"); 
      }
    });
  });
    
</script>
```

and here is my php code

```
<?php
```

include('our/db_connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['input'])){

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM parcels WHERE reference_number LIKE '{$input}'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){?>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-4">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>tracking num</th>
                    <th>sender contact</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $ref = $row['reference_number'];
                    $sender = $row['sender_name'];
                    $from = $row['from_branch_id'];
                    $to = $row['to_branch_id'];

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $ref;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $sender;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $from;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $to;?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                }
```

?>

```
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php 
    
}else{
    echo "No Parcel Found";
}
```

}
?>

Comment: So, what happens exactly? And what is supposed to happen? I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, watch out for MYSQL injection! This code will let any site visitor do anything they want to your database! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496 for the best way to avoid injection (using prepared statements).

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding the div but not showing it again when you have ajax result.

Write the ajax code like:

```
if (input != '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'livesearch.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { input: input },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#searchresult').html(data);
            $('#searchresult').show();
        },
    });
} else {
    $('#searchresult').hide();
}
```

Here I am showing the `$('#searchresult')` again after your have response and you replaced the HTML in `$('#searchresult')`

Comment: This answer should also include the bigger issue of the mysql injection vulnerability. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Answer (score 0):

As after searching first and then emptying your search input using `keyup` keyboard event
and the input `value == ""` there you hide the search result Id and you in this code not add code for displaying the search result Id after empty input value when you again search so you have to add a show or `display = 'block'` as show in the below code. to fix this issue

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#live_search").keyup(function () {
      var input = $(this).val();
      //alert(input);
  
      if (input != "") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "livesearch.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: { input: input },
          success: function (data) {
            $("#searchresult").html(data);
            $("#searchresult").show();
            //Or add
            $("#searchresult").css("display", "block");
          }
        });
      } else {
        $("#searchresult").css("display", "none");
      }
    });
  });
```